# Post variable with onclick?

Tags: php, html

How can I $_POST information from one page to another by clicking a link? No forms or submit boxes, just if the end user clicks on a link, it will post pertinent information in the opened link.

Pseudocode, but:

```
//On first page
<a href="./page.php" onclick="post" value="var">Click me!</a>
...
//On the page the above links to
$variable = $_POST["var"];
```

Something that I considered is the following, which although less than pretty, works. I'd like it so it's a post and not a get.

```
//On first page
<a href="./page.php?var=<?php echo $variable; ?>">Click me!</a>
...
//On second page
$variable = $_GET["var"];
```

Comment: I've never used AJAX before.

Comment: can we use jquery (it's much easier than js on its own, especially for this)

Comment: Why do you want it POST, not GET?

Comment: and is the page to relocate or is this a post and stay put?

Comment: GET displays the information in the URL, whereas with POST it does not. I do not wish an end user to just edit the URL with whatever value they wish.

@popnoodles, when the user would click the hyperlink, it would direct to a new page.

Comment: @riista, if you are doing it for security reasons then that won't work as all requests can be tampered with.

Comment: So I open Inspect element, change the HTML to whatever I like and then POST whatever I want. It's probably a better idea to start a new question saying what you want to achieve. This is not the resolution to security  you're looking for.

Comment: it can be achieved using jQuery Ajax..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<a href="link.php" class="post">submit content using link</a>

 <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $(".post").on("click",function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://www.yourwebsite.com/page.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
                        success: function(response){
                              //do action  
                        },
                        error: function(){
                              // do action
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**[Reference Link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you don't do this:

//On first page

```
<a href="./page.php?var=value">Click me!</a>
```

...
//On the page the above links to

```
$variable = $_GET['var'];
```

**UPDATE:**

As per your above comment:

> GET displays the information in the URL, whereas with POST it does
>   not. I do not wish an end user to just edit the URL with whatever
>   value they wish. @popnoodles, when the user would click the hyperlink,
>   it would direct to a new page. – riista

You are trying to do this for *security* reasons, as such **neither** approach is a good way to do it using GET or AJAX is *both* unsafe as *both* can be tampered with. You need to re-think what you are trying to protect and how you can check if the data submitted is valid.

Comment: The OP doesn't want `$_GET`

Comment: "**Post** variable with onclick?"  "How can I **$_POST** information from one page to another by clicking a link?"

Comment: So OP does not want the page to be refreshed? If so needs to specify that. However according to above comments OP does not want people modifying the value, which would likely mean a security concern, thus this is a completely different question.

Comment: OP has now. They wanted to prevent users from deciding what they want as the var. Have since commented that that won't work.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  Read the question properly

Comment: @YourCommonSense your post "so what" was before OP said anything related to whether it is GET/POST and the comments OP has made do not back up your "so what?"

Comment: @cryptic But the point here is the OP doesn't want the end user to change his request from url,right? Forget about tampering post data.. Using mere `GET` would look so uncool if you have security concerns

Comment: @BhuvanRikka, "forget about tampering post data" wow, just wow! So aesthetics overrule security in your reasoning? You know what I'm going to remove all the doors in my house because who cares if someone can walk in when they want, the doors look ugly, and that's more important! I'm done with this debate.

Comment: @cryptic So you'll lock all your doors and hang a key to it easily visible to everyone,huh!? Well,i don't have a problem with that.. _I'm done with this debate_  Like i have time for it o.O

Comment: @BhuvanRikka, you might want to read https://www.owasp.org/images/5/56/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v3.pdf so you have a better understanding of how web application security works. Security through obscurity as you are doing is useless. But don't take my word for it, but rather the IT security industry.

Answer (score 3):

To choose between GET and POST is simple

- POST should be used to modify state of the server.
- all other cases goes for GET

So, you have to use GET in your case, not POST.
Security matters are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Add an click  event listener and send the request to another page.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap your "selections" in a form and use a button like so..

```
<style type="text/css">
/* just styling the overall menu */
#my-post-link ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:cadetblue;
  font-size:1.1em;
  font-weight:600;
  padding:0.45em;
  line-height: 1.75em;
}
/* following line would allow you to create a horizontal menu */
#my-post-link ul li{display:inline;white-space:nowrap;} 
#my-post-link button {
  background-color: transparent; /* <-- removes the gray button */
  border: none; /* <-- removes the border around the button */
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#my-post-link button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: cadetblue;
  cursor: pointer; /* <-- makes the button text act like a link on hover */
}
</style>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post">
  <div id="my-post-link"><ul>
    <li><button name="select-me" type="submit" value="var" onclick=\"myForm.action='./page.php';return true;\">Click me!</li>
  </ul></div>
</form>
```

This will POST the value "var" to page.php with the key "select-me", so you would read that variable with...

```
$variable = $_POST["select-me"];
```

You could also further style the button(s) with pseudo classes to make them behave even more like a regular text link, but I think you get the idea.

If you want to see what variables are POSTing back to your page, you can drop this code in somewhere:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $i++;
  ${$key} = $value;
  echo "<!-- //[{$i}] {$key}:{$value} -->\n";
}
```

You can also use var_dump($_POST) to view the POSTed data

Answer (score 0):

you may also

```
$.get('./page.php?param=true&data=1', function(data){$('#content').append(data);});
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: you can post data like this. (param=true&data=1)
page.php will be load in #content div

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to click a link to logout and you want it by post method which is more secure. You can do this.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="logout.php" data-method="post">Logout (John)</a>
```

Just add data-method="post" to the link attribute.