# Hiding arguments in http call

Tags: php

I use this to pass an argument (fullname).

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function listbox_update(){
  var fullname = document.getElementById("listboxid").value;
  document.location.href="{$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]}?fullname="+fullname;}
</script>
```

Is there a way to pass the argument such that it can NOT be seen in the http URL?
I know about POST.

```
$listboxselected = $_POST['listbox'];
```

I would use POST instead, so that the argument is not present in the URL, but I can't, because I'm using the javascript as an On Click event.

```
<select id="listboxid" name=listbox onChange="listbox_update()"></br>
```

The On Click event works perfectly. But I don't like seeing all my variables in the URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133502/post-variable-with-onclick

Comment: just use `XMLHttpRequest` object

Comment: Follow-up question.  On my desktop PC with Chrome a listbox appears as, well, a listbox.  On my Android smartphone Chrome browser a listbox appears as a popup listbox with checkboxes. I like the Android Chrome browser checkbox style, is there a way to force that style to come up on a Windows PC Chrome browser.  I assume not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `<select>` in a `<form>` and then in `onchange` submit the form.

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
    <select id="listboxid" name="fullname" onChange="listbox_update()">
        <option>here the options</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and the `listbox_update`

```
function listbox_update () {
    document.getElementById('form').submit();
}
```

Another option would be to use Ajax, but since your original script reloads the page, then the first approach follows this way.

Comment: Awesome.  I already had everything in a Form. So this approach took 20 seconds to implement. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do that only by `JS` then you can go with Ajax.

```
 function listbox_update(){
  var fullname = document.getElementById("listboxid").value;
    $.ajax({
        data: { fullname: fullname },
        url: <?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(msg){
          //some function here
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have only 2 solutions for this:
1) Either you must implement AJAX like below:

```
  function listbox_update()
  {
     var fullname = $("#listboxid").val();
     $.ajax({
        data: "fullname="+fullname,
        url: <?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(msg){
          console.log("Message :"+msg);
        }
    });
}
```

2) Or go with form submission.

```
function listbox_update()
{
  $('#your_form_id').attr('action', <?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>);
  $('#your_form_id').submit();
}
```