# Passing variable to function doesn't work when using query string

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

**EDIT:**

**I was trying to pass a reference to an object to another file. The answer seems to be to keep everything in one file and use different modals for different views.**

---

What works:

I'm passing an object to a function via an onClick event and everything works fine.

```
$('.senator2016').on("click", function(){
    $('.navSecondary .yr').removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
    countyInfo(elections.election2016senator);
});
```

Now, I'm trying to send the same data to a new page. I put the key information into a query string, parse it and send it to the function but ... it doesn't work.

When clicking on a link on the first page I pass a query string to the second page and then parse it

```
    var getElection;
    getElection = window.location.href;
    getElection = getElection.split("?")[1];
```

and then send it to the function

```
    console.log(getElection);
    countyInfo(getElection);
```

The first line on the console panel is this console.log (it's from state2-large.html)

```
    function countyInfo(selected_race){
          console.log(selected_race);
          var getYear   =   selected_race.electionDetails.year;
          var getOffice =   selected_race.electionDetails.office;
```

The above variables (getYear and getOffice) are getting information from the following object:

```
var elections={
  election2016senator:{
    electionDetails:{
        year:2016,
        office:"Senator",
        caption:"2016 Senatorial Candidates"
    },
```

The console panel below shows the two console.log calls
Notice they are strings.
The error msg shows that the function was unable to read year in the getYear variable.

And below that is what is passed when I send the information via the onClick event (shown above) it sends an object.

Image below show the console.logs, 
then the error
then what the onClick event sends

[image]

Comment: it seems your objects are not being defined properly or even received at all... Show your "sending" and "receiving" code.

Comment: @JoeDF - added more code

Comment: You really have not posted enough code. For example, what does that `countyInfo()` function look like? That's where the error is.

Comment: Dont know who downvoted but welcome to SO. Where patience and sympathy is near non-existent.

Comment: We need to see how you define the object. You're not posting enough code.

Comment: It would also be good to know exactly what that query string looks like. In the "click" handler, you're passing some value from an `elections` object. What does that string look like?

Comment: @JoeDF - added more code. Hopefully there is enough now. :)

Comment: what does the `console.log(selected_race);` display in `countyInfo()` ?

Comment: Apparently you pass the countyInfo() function a string. You mention you parse it, can you show the code for that?

Comment: @JoeDF -  it displays elections.election2016senator - this is the second line in the console panel  (state-elections.js:38)

Comment: Yes, but what actual content is in the obj?

Comment: @JoeDF - See edit. I was trying to pass an object to another file and no matter what I tried it didn't work. The solution seems to be to keep everything in one file and to use a modal for different views. Thanks so much for helping.

Answer (score 2):

`selected_race` is still a string at this point. Try `countyInfo(elections[getElection])` to actually access the object.

Comment: Thank you. That didn't work. Still wasn't able to reference the object.

Comment: @Mayo Couldn't help but continue the search, maybe this could be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133502/post-variable-with-onclick